# google sheet count groups reported month wise

Tags: excel, sum, countif

I have a data table that contains the data of reporting groups, date wise for 3 months
for

example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCYS3.png)

I want to count the simplify the data in the below format

I need a google sheet formula to calculate this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFMRQ.png)

Comment: Share a sample copy of google-sheet so that we can work.

Comment: [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gr0xoJ73uUULbYVGu6UZMLxh_HOwYCVTbTcD5o6m8ws/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What data you want to count? `Y`, `N` or `Nil`. Give a try on `=SUMPRODUCT(('Reporting Groups'!$C$2:$CO$48<>"")*('Reporting Groups'!$B$2:$B$48=$B2)*('Reporting Groups'!$C$1:$CO$1=C$1))`.

Comment: I want to count both `Y` & `Nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=SUMPRODUCT((('Reporting Groups'!$C$2:$CO$48="Y")+('Reporting Groups'!$C$2:$CO$48="Nil"))*('Reporting Groups'!$B$2:$B$48=$B2)*('Reporting Groups'!$C$1:$CO$1=C$1))
```

Comment: Thanks, I Tried this formula it's displays all the values as `1`, I want to count how many times reporting has been done month-wise.

Comment: @AbhijithMulik Can you please check now?

Comment: I checked it, I need data for the `whole month`. can you alter the formula to fetch data for the `whole month`?

Comment: @AbhijithMulik Formula updated. Check your sheet now. And if it helps then accept the answer (tick mark it and upvote).

Comment: Thank you, @harun24hr. The formula fetches the data as I required.

Comment: @AbhijithMulik Then please tick mark the answer.